# Insert Flickr json data into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, json, geolocation, flickr

I got the JSON data using Geolocation and Flickr API. Now I am trying to insert that data into MYSQL database. I am able to store the latitude and longitude into the database. I need help with the flickr json data. I am not sure how do I insert it into the database. Any help would be appreciated

```
    <?php
require 'database.php';
if ($_POST['address'])
{   
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $string = str_replace (" ", "+", urlencode($address));
    $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$string.'&key=AIzaSyD5Dqe3SK3kKOZqKT5Rxk_JZskcoCf4J3g');

    $output=json_decode($geocode, true);
    $lat = $output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
    $lon = $output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($output);
    echo "</pre>";

    $insta = file_get_contents('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=eabad3d02e824ce76245158db270c855&lat='.$lat.'&lon='.$lon.'&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1');
    $out = json_decode($insta);
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($out);
    echo "</pre>";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO geo (latitude, longitude) VALUES ($lat, $lon)";

        if ($db->query($sql) !== False) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
        } 
        else {
                echo "Record Entry Failed";
            }


        $photos = $out->photos->photo;
        foreach($photos as $photo) {
            $id= $photo->id;
            $owner = $photo->owner;
            $secret = $photo->secret;
            $server = $photo->server;
            $farm = $photo->farm;
            $title= $photo->title;
            $sql = "INSERT INTO flickr (id, owner, secret, server, farm, title) VALUES ($id, $owner, $secret, $server, $farm, $title)";
            if ($db->query($sql) !== false) {
            echo "New record created successfully";
            } 
            else{
                echo "FAILED";
            }
            $url = 'http://farm'.$photo->farm.'.staticflickr.com'.'/'.$photo->server.'/'.$photo->id.'_'.$photo->secret.'_b'.'.jpg';
            echo '<img src="'.$url.'"/><br/>';
            echo "<pre>";
            print_r($id);
            echo "</pre>";



}   

    $conn->close();

}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>geogram</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="address"/>
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
<br/>

</body>
</html>
```

Database tables

```
CREATE TABLE `geo` (
  `search_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `latitude` Decimal(20,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` Decimal(20,15) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`search_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB ;

CREATE TABLE `flickr` (
  `photo_id` int(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `owner` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `search_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `secret` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `server` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `farm` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `title` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`photo_id`),
  KEY `search_id` (`search_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `search_id` FOREIGN KEY (`search_id`) REFERENCES `geo` (`search_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=62 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Parsed JSON data:
    stdClass Object
    (
        [photos] => stdClass Object
            (
                [page] => 1
                [pages] => 15452
                [perpage] => 20
                [total] => 309028
                [photo] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [id] => 30662996107
                                [owner] => 9449122@N02
                                [secret] => 4010d5b691
                                [server] => 1925
                                [farm] => 2
                                [title] => White Ginger - October 27, 2018
                                [ispublic] => 1
                                [isfriend] => 0
                                [isfamily] => 0
                            )

```
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 31731641758
                            [owner] => 9449122@N02
                            [secret] => 3fa8ec438f
                            [server] => 1915
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => White Ginger - October 27, 2018
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 43784782480
                            [owner] => 24243188@N04
                            [secret] => bb4659987b
                            [server] => 1975
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => DSC_0480
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [3] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45602624641
                            [owner] => 24243188@N04
                            [secret] => d8ea61ec54
                            [server] => 1913
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => DSC_0481
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [4] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 43784781020
                            [owner] => 24243188@N04
                            [secret] => 22e8a21890
                            [server] => 1950
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => DSC_0482
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [5] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45551846532
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => 87ccaabf1f
                            [server] => 1978
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_2871
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [6] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45551808352
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => f6e43efb0c
                            [server] => 1966
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_2897
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [7] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 30661366227
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => 2a666245ca
                            [server] => 1956
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_2899
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [8] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 44877542714
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => 40341bae71
                            [server] => 1961
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_2900
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [9] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 31729843048
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => 8bdc59bec0
                            [server] => 1934
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_3015
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [10] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45551677842
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => ee7fb953fa
                            [server] => 1973
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_3016
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [11] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 30661216397
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => e848122232
                            [server] => 1960
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_3018
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [12] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45551663032
                            [owner] => 21151100@N08
                            [secret] => 1b8cd9101e
                            [server] => 1974
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => IMG_3019
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [13] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 43775021470
                            [owner] => 12203537@N08
                            [secret] => d52463646f
                            [server] => 1945
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => 
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [14] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45592785101
                            [owner] => 12203537@N08
                            [secret] => 18d9bdb5ec
                            [server] => 1979
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => 
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [15] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45592771261
                            [owner] => 12203537@N08
                            [secret] => 3beffc8e5c
                            [server] => 1962
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => Halloween at Mary’s
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [16] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 43768485760
                            [owner] => 54059915@N07
                            [secret] => 5a888480cd
                            [server] => 1913
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => Crystal Cathedral bell tower
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [17] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 30644568537
                            [owner] => 54059915@N07
                            [secret] => e759c4ef84
                            [server] => 1931
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => External staircase on Richard Neutra's "Tower of Hope"
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [18] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 44860933144
                            [owner] => 54059915@N07
                            [secret] => 9cf81232e6
                            [server] => 1950
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => Richard Neutra arboretum in Garden Grove, CA
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                    [19] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [id] => 45535214712
                            [owner] => 54059915@N07
                            [secret] => 0423fca595
                            [server] => 1914
                            [farm] => 2
                            [title] => Richer Neutra's "Tower of Hope"
                            [ispublic] => 1
                            [isfriend] => 0
                            [isfamily] => 0
                        )

                )

        )

    [stat] => ok
)
```

Comment: On one line you refer to `$row['results']` but on the next you refer to `$row->lat`. So is it an object or an array? Since you say the lat and long don't get inserted, I'm assuming it's an array. Voting to close for typo.

Comment: I tried to insert it as an array but did not work. I tried $row[ ' ['results'] [0] ['geometry'] ['location'] ['lat'] ' ]

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. i am not including "search_id" into query because your schema of geo table saying that it is auto increment.

```
                                if ($_REQUEST['address'])
                            {   
                                $address = $_REQUEST['address'];
                                $string = str_replace (" ", "+", urlencode($address));
                                $geocode=file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$string.'&key=AIzaSyD5Dqe3SK3kKOZqKT5Rxk_JZskcoCf4J3g');

                                $output=json_decode($geocode, true);
                                $lat = $output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lat'];
                                $lon = $output['results'][0]['geometry']['location']['lng'];

                                $insta = file_get_contents('https://api.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=eabad3d02e824ce76245158db270c855&lat='.$lat.'&lon='.$lon.'&per_page=20&format=json&nojsoncallback=1');
                                $out = json_decode($insta);

                                $sql = "insert into geo (latitude,longitude) values(?,?)";
                                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->bind_param('ss',$lat,$long);

                                foreach($output['results'][0]['geometry']['bounds']  as $row) {
                                    $lat = $row['lat'];
                                    $long = $row['lng'];
                                    $stmt->execute();
                                }
                                $stmt->close();

                                $sql = "insert into flickr (photo_id, owner, secret, server, farm, title) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
                                $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);
                                $stmt->bind_param('ssssss',$id,$owner,$secret,$server,$farm,$title);

                                $photos = $out->photos->photo;
                                foreach($photos as $photo) {
                                    $id= $photo->id;
                                    $owner = $photo->owner;
                                    $secret = $photo->secret;
                                    $server = $photo->server;
                                    $farm = $photo->farm;
                                    $title= $photo->title;
                                    $rc = $stmt->execute();
                                    if ( false===$rc ) {
                                      die('execute() failed: ' . htmlspecialchars($stmt->error));
                                    }
                                    $tid = $stmt->insert_id;

                                    if ($tid) {
                                        echo "New record created successfully";
                                    } 
                                    else {
                                        echo "Record Entry Failed";
                                    }
                                } 

                            }
```

Comment: Can you help me with the flickr json data

Comment: i was running it to my local machine (http://localhost/stackoverflow/test.php?address=saket,new%20delhi) and it is successfully inserting data to geo table. check the json data after using the address which is in my URL or share the address which you are passing in your post request.

Comment: I tried to insert the latitude and longitude without using the prepare statement and that solved the problem for me, I have updated the code. But now I am having trouble with the flickr json file. I cannot insert it into my database for some reason. Can you also help me out with that?

Comment: please check my sql statement for the flickr json in the code above.

Comment: will you share the mysql error in execution of that query? correct me if i am wrong that now you are having problem in inserting the data to "flickr" table?

Comment: Yes, I am having trouble with Flickr. I have used a foreach loop, since it is an object and not an array

Comment: you have to do some modifiction in your table structure as well as in your code.
1)  you are taking photo_id column as int(11). change it to bigint(20) because you are inserting the values beyond the range of integer.
2) your query is wrong.you are using id column which does not exist in your flickr table. use photo_id instead of id.

$sql = "INSERT INTO flickr (photo_id, owner, secret, server, farm, title) VALUES ('".$id."', '".$owner."', '".$secret."', '".$server."', '".$farm."', '".$title."')";

Hope you will not get any problem after this.